# iOS Developer Program: I misspelled my address, and now I cannot cancel my enrolment and try again

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, developer-program

I tried to enrol to the iOS Developer program a few months ago, but was unable to do so because my card wasn't acceptable due to some reasons.

I now have a new card which *can* be used with Apple. But I changed my address in the mean time. My account is still stuck at the previous enrolment, with the previous address.  I cannot seem to cancel this enrolment, or start a new one. I cannot edit my information either, which shows up fine at My Apple ID.

How do I get out of this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call Developer Support directly to get them to look at the specifics for your account:

- https://developer.apple.com/contact/

Choose the **Enrollment and Account** link and sign in to get your options. It your AppleID doesn't work to sign in, then you need to contact the online store in your country and ask them to connect you with the developer support team. In the US it's 1-800-MY-APPLE.

Comment: So there's no way for me to do it without contacting them? I'm already in touch with them on email, but responses are slow.

Comment: @duci9y in my experience, this isn't fixable in a self-service fashion. Did you already pay for the developer program and fail at the verification steps or were you unable to complete the initial transaction on the web store?

Comment: I tried to purchase it, received an "Acknowledgement of Order Request" email, but my card was not charged and I did not get an account. :(

Comment: You likely will have to key off that web order number and start with Apple Store support. The last time this happened to me, developer support took 10 minutes to fix everything. I did have to call the next day as they were open 7am to 7pm central time on the developer support side.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Sounds like a common issue. I could call them up, only if my country had developer phone support. Thanks anyways! I will wait for the emails.