# Can't log in to Apple Developer to enroll

Tags: app-store-connect, developer-program

Today I opened new Apple account for enrolling Apple Developer Program for iOS as an individual developer. I followed these steps

- Verify mail
- Go Developer menu
- Click to join iOS program
- Enroll now button

After these steps Apple opens developer login page and asks me to log in again. Problem is it asks again and again although I've enter information correctly.

Any idea what is happening?

EDIT:
I think it is common problem according to this link https://devforums.apple.com/thread/238081?tstart=0

Comment: Which developer program precisely are you joining? https://developer.apple.com/programs/ Individual, Enterprise or Educational?

Comment: I am planning to join Individual program but I cannot even go to the selection page

Answer (score 1):

To join the individual developer program you first buy the entry from the Apple online store at store.apple.com (perhaps in your local country's store if you don't work out of or live in the USA.)

From there, you pay with whatever Apple ID you want since you can choose later to join with that or another Apple ID in the developer portal called iTunes Connect.

You have two sources of support while buying any paid developer account - the first is web and phone sales from http://store.apple.com - you can and should call them and explain your difficulties and they will help you with your purchase. If they can't resolve the issue they may refer you to AppleCare for AppleID issues and/or Apple Developer Support for specific issues on the developer program:

- [iOS Developer Program: I misspelled my address, and now I cannot cancel my enrolment and try again](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/122939/5472)
- https://developer.apple.com/contact/
- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5622

---

As to what's happening, it's hard to guess - but if you don't have an AppleID that works to log into the online store - work that out first and make the purchase. Once you've spent money on the purchase, you will have a very narrow list of things to check/correct with the help of support if needed. If you can't get an Apple ID to work for the initial purchase, that too is pretty easy to sort with Apple's phone or online support. Worst case, ask a second question here with exact URL you are using and details on which URL you can't get logged in to.

Comment: I cannot even login there https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php I think problem is more than just enrolment issue

Comment: Indeed - if you can't log in to appleid.apple.com or store.apple.com then start with the online store support to get your ID in order. It's probably a problem on the server end that you can't resolve without someone looking at things on the Apple side.

Comment: I can log in to appleid.apple.com and store.apple.com ,purchase some apps but I cannot log in to contact support or enrolment

Comment: If you can't log in, just call the Apple Store online phone support number for your country. Until everything is fixed, you have to avoid developer support and work through the store support team.